# error con un datePicker en react

Tags: reactjs

Estoy utilizando un DATE PICKER en react para que el usuario pueda ingresar su fecha de nacimiento, hice todo tal  y como esta en la documentacion pero aun asi me esta dando un error que no se a que se debe, les dejo mi fomulario, aun no esta terminado

```
import React, { Component, ChangeEvent, ReactNode, FormEvent } from 'react'
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button'
import { TextField } from '@material-ui/core'
import Select from '@material-ui/core/Select';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import InputLabel from '@material-ui/core/InputLabel';
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
import { KeyboardDatePicker } from '@material-ui/pickers';

import './css/main.css'

export default class formulario extends Component
    <{}, {nombre: string, apellido: string, usuario: string, email: string, password: string, 
reppassword: string, sexo: string, date: string}> {

    constructor(props: any){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            nombre: '',
            apellido: '',
            usuario: '',
            email: '',
            sexo: '',
            date: '',
            password: '',
            reppassword: ''
        }

        this.SexoChange = this.SexoChange.bind(this);
        this.NombreChangue = this.NombreChangue.bind(this)
        this.ApellidoChangue = this.ApellidoChangue.bind(this)
        this.UsuarioChangue = this.UsuarioChangue.bind(this)
        this.EmailChangue = this.EmailChangue.bind(this)
        this.PasswordChangue = this.PasswordChangue.bind(this)
        this.RepPasswordChangue = this.RepPasswordChangue.bind(this)
        this.DateChangue = this.DateChangue.bind(this)
    }

    SexoChange(event: ChangeEvent<{ name?: string | undefined; value: string | unknown; }>, child: ReactNode): any{
    let dato: any = event.target.value
    this.setState({sexo: dato})
};

NombreChangue(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): any{
    this.setState({nombre: event.target.value})
}

ApellidoChangue(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): any{
    this.setState({apellido: event.target.value})
}

UsuarioChangue(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): any{
    this.setState({usuario: event.target.value})
}

EmailChangue(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): any{
    this.setState({email: event.target.value})
}

PasswordChangue(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): any{
    this.setState({password: event.target.value})
}

RepPasswordChangue(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): any{
    this.setState({password: event.target.value})
}

DateChangue(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>){
    this.setState({date: event.target.value})
}

register(e: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>): any{
    console.log(this.state)
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="container-form">
            <div style={{ margin: "auto", textAlign: "center", marginBottom: "1rem"}}>
                <h1>Registrate</h1>
                <span>Simple, Facil y rapido.!</span>
            </div>
            <form style={{ margin: "auto", textAlign: "center"}} onSubmit={this.register}>
                <TextField
                onChange={this.NombreChangue}
                className="input-register"
                label="Nombre/s" />
                <TextField
                onChange={this.ApellidoChangue}
                className="input-register"
                label="Apellido/s" />
                <TextField
                onChange={this.UsuarioChangue}
                className="input-register"
                label="Usuario" />
                <TextField
                onChange={this.EmailChangue}
                className="input-register"
                label="Email" /><br/>
                <FormControl className="input-register">
                <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Sexo</InputLabel>
                <Select
                className="input-register-select"
                labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
                id="demo-simple-select"
                value={this.state.sexo}
                onChange={this.SexoChange}
                >
                <MenuItem value={'hombre'}>Hombre</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value={'mujer'}>Mujer</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value={'indefinido'}>Prefiero no decirlo</MenuItem>
                </Select>
            </FormControl>
            <KeyboardDatePicker
            margin="normal"
            id="date-picker-dialog"
            label="Date picker dialog"
            format="MM/dd/yyyy"
            value={this.state.date}
            onChange={this.DateChangue}
            KeyboardButtonProps={{
                'aria-label': 'change date',
            }}
            />
            <TextField
            type="password"
            autoComplete="new-password"
            onChange={this.PasswordChangue}
            className="input-register"
            label="Contraseña" />
            <TextField
            type="password"
            autoComplete="new-password"
            onChange={this.RepPasswordChangue}
            className="input-register"
            label="Confirme su contraseña" />
            <Button
            type="submit"
            style={{ display: 'block', margin: '1rem auto', width: '50%'}}
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            >Registrarme
            </Button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

les dejo una captura del error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que pasa si ponés el import así? import  KeyboardDatePicker from '@material-ui/pickers';

Comment: me dice que no contiene una exportacion por defecto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si es con relación a `https://www.npmjs.com/package/@material-ui/pickers` (asumo por la referencia a `MuiPickersUtilsProvider`), entiendo que el error menciona que el componente espera una prop `utils`.

```
...
...
import { MuiPickersUtilsProvider } from '@material-ui/pickers';
import DateFnsUtils from '@date-io/date-fns';

function App() {
  return (
    <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
      <Root />
    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: probe con tu solucion pero me devuelve el siguiente error `Module not found: Can't resolve '@date-io/date-fns'` tengo que instalar esete modulo? es raro por que en la documentacion que lei en react no lei en ningun aparatado este modulo

Comment: ¿Me podrías compartir el enlace a la documentación. Yo estoy revisando [https://material-ui-pickers.dev/getting-started/installation](https://material-ui-pickers.dev/getting-started/installation) y creo que sí es necesario que instales un modulo extra para el manejo de fechas.

Comment: https://material-ui.com/es/components/pickers/ eso es lo que estaba leyendo, la documentacion que mostraste vos no la habia visto, ni siquiera sabia de su existemcia, pero ahora si me quedo todo mas claro, mushcas gracias